# Помогите с заданием по Maple

Tags: maple

Дан файл test1.txt с экспериментальными данными с 2мя столбцами-массивами.

показания 2 столбца зависят от показаний 1го. истинное значение 2го массива должно быть 5,1.
поэтому ножно получить значение домножающего коэффицента для 2 го массива так, чтобы его значение было равно 5,1

для начала посторить график 1 го массива (так нагляднее), выбрать несколько значений (на усмотрение, например 10). назовем ее "Основная таблица"
получить для данного набора точек домножающие коэффиценты. 
в итоге у нас есть набор точек. значения всех остальных домножающих коэффициентов ищется через кусочно-линейную интерполяцию.

нужен скрипт, который бы находил значение домножающего коэффицента для любого значения 1 массива на основе выбранного набор значений из "Основной таблицы"

Вопрос: не совсем понимаю, что имеется в виду здесь под домножающим коэффициентом?

Comment: Наверное, стоит спросить у преподавателя )

Comment: Преподавателя нет, это для себя - самообразование

Comment: К сожалению, подсказать не могу. Меня даже "истинное значение массива" очень озадачивает.

Comment: дк именно в этом и дело, ну возможно, что домножающий коэффициент это коэффициент пропорциональности, а истинное значение 2-го массива это описка, и имелось в виду "истинное значение домножающего коэффициента"

Comment: либо истинное значение - это мат.ожидание